# xcode ios how to set the Table View Cell on a fixed position

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have created a `tableView` in grouped style with the storyboard. Now I want to set the `TableViewCell` on a fixed position in this `TableView` e.g. `x: 10 y:10.`

So that the layout don't break on different devices(iPhone iPad).

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by fixed position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understand your making an universal app and  want to add a tableview in your application. First of all you mentioned that your using Storyboard, So defiantly your using two different storyboards one is for iPhone and another is for iPad. For making position consistence follow below steps

1. Take an outlet for `UITableView`
2. Make a condition in code with basic idioms

   ```
   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       // iPad-specific code
   } else {
       // iPhone-specific code
   }
   ```
3. adjust table view position like this

   ```
   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
               // iPad-specific code
   yourTableview.frame = CGRectMake(10,20,300,400);

   } 
   else {
               // iPhone-specific code
   yourTableview.frame = CGRectMake(10,20,150,200);

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add tableView by programmatically like this, and it will solve your problem :

```
UITableView* yourTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 40) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self.view addSubview:yourTableView];
```

Of course you have to set delegate and other things... but this will solve the width and height problem

Answer (score 0):

Use Static Cells in your table view. As a bonus, you can create outlets directly from your table cell to your table view controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way: 
I used ajay solution, and create a subclass of UITableViewCell. In this class I used

```
 -(void)layoutSubviews()
 {
      if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
         {
             CGRect frame = self.backgroundView.frame;
             frame.origin.x -= x;
             frame.size.width += x*2;
             self.backgroundView.frame = frame;
```

Thanks for help